# Pointers for good books for HTML5 mobile architecture

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, jquery-mobile, sencha-touch-2

I am looking for a good reference book for HTML5 mobile frameworks architecture which can help to build up the design and architecture knowledge, specifically designed for entry level mobile architects. Any reference would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, Finally I got a good match in the form of 'Architecting Mobile Solutions for the Enterprise by Dino Esposito.

I was looking for a book which help me to make good design/architecture decisions while architect a mobile website. This book help to broaden your views about the mobile architecture paradigm with neatly detailed explanations and good examples.

Since this book was published by Microsoft Press, I thought it will be biased to Windows Phones but it is not. It has covered all the major mobile platforms (iOS, Android and Windows) with couple of other good examples related to development with jQM and PhoneGap.

This book is good for anyone who wants to deep dive into mobile development.